# WCF Duplex service and Android client? Any possibilities

Tags: java, android, .net, wcf, duplex

I have created a **WCF duplex service** and client in .NET and its working fine and its pretty good also.
Now I wish to make an Android client. I have used **kSoap** previously for webservices and those are good for client to service connections.
But in the case of **duplex** communication in which **I need the service to sent message to client**, I dont know how to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the duplex bindings are interoperable

At this point polling might be your simplest option. Further down the line maybe you could use something like WebSockets (WCF supports them in the next version - 4.5)